# Get data from another table W/O associations

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHP, and trying to pull data from a table outside my current controller. The only thing I can find online is about using associations and belongsTo and such, however these two items shouldn't be related. I simply want to pull data from another table at will.

Comment: "Any help?" isn't a very nice way to ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the loadModel inside your functions.

```
$this->loadModel('User', 2);
$user = $this->User->read();
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answers. I tried both, but am getting an error in which the function (from the other model) is being sent as an SQL query instead of being executed as a function. It loads fine either way... it just keeps sending the function as a query. I've tried looking this up online and someone said it could be caused by CakePHP not finding the model, but creating one still has no effect.

Comment: @user726319 : can u post some piece of code both `controller` and `model`

Comment: @user726319: please post the error message, too.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want to access different model (not the related to the controller) you can use

```
class SomeController extends AppController {
  var $uses = array('Model1', 'Model2');
  // and then later in the code you can use them like this
  function index() {
    $this->Model1->doStuff;
    $this->Model2->doStuff;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! See my continuation below at second answer.

Comment: I agree that this will get the things solved but the better method is `$this->loadModel()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$user=App::Model('User');
$user->find('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

either

```
//only controller
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
$res = $this->MyModel->find(...)
```

or

```
//everywhere
$this->MyModel = ClassRegistry::init('MyModel');
$res = $this->MyModel->find(...)
```